# What is this if block doing in this decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

I've been working with the [JabberBot framework](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jabberbot) recently and am finally trying to understand its decorator `@botcmd` which is used to specify methods that can be executed in chat.

```
def botcmd(*args, **kwargs):
    """Decorator for bot command functions"""

    def decorate(func, hidden=False, name=None, thread=False):
        setattr(func, '_jabberbot_command', True)
        setattr(func, '_jabberbot_command_hidden', hidden)
        setattr(func, '_jabberbot_command_name', name or func.__name__)
        setattr(func, '_jabberbot_command_thread', thread)  # Experimental!
        return func

    if len(args):
        return decorate(args[0], **kwargs)
    else:
        return lambda func: decorate(func, **kwargs)
```

I understand everything except the purpose of the `if/else` block at the end. What exactly does the `if/else` block do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the decorator is used normally, for example in the code snippet below, the `botcmd` function receives a single argument, namely the function `mycmd` itself, and so `args = [mycmd]`. The `if` block then executes, since `len(args) = 1` and returns the decorated version of `mycmd`.

```
@botcmd
def mycmd(self,mess,args):
    return 'Message'
```

The more difficult to intuit case happens when `botcmd` is called without any positional arguments, but possibly with keyword arguments. In this case, the user can easily define a new decorator with specific keyword arguments. For example, the following decorator `hiddencmd` can be used exactly as `botcmd` except that `hidden` will be `True`.

```
hiddencmd = botcmd(hidden=True)

@hiddencmd
def mycmd(self,mess,args):
    return 'Message'
```

Which is then equivalent to:

```
@botcmd(hidden=True)
def mycmd(self,mess,args):
    return 'Message'
```

I should also note that `hiddencmd` will not accept any keyword arguments, and so `hiddencmd(hidden=False)` would throw an error. In conclusion, it can be used as a small shortcut to increase readability and eliminate potential duplicate code.